# Create Azure Kubernetes ingress controller to limit 1 connection per pod

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, azure-container-service

I'm using Azure Kubernetes Service and have a unique scenario where I want to allow only one connection per pod. I used the "advanced" networking option to set up my cluster such that each pod has its own internal IP address. The problem is, all of these pods are behind a public load balancer IP address, and the load balancer decides where to route the traffic.

I need to either A) set up a rule such that the load balancer only allows one connection per pod and routes new traffic to new pods, 1 per request, or B) set up an ingress controller to do the same. I think B) is the solution but I have no clear path on how to do this. I see that you can route by URL, but you'd have to set up a rule for each pod, which is definitely not a good idea. Is there any way to set up a rule that just limits 1 session per pod? Or some other method that works similarly.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean to limit connection per pod? What connection? The service to the pod?

Comment: I want end users to be able to connect to these pods, via sockets, and I want the load balancer to detect and redirect additional users to their own pods.

Comment: You can route the request only to one pod or one deployment through the service, I do not really understand what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very good question. Based on solutions you suggested in the second part of your question, I would like to add my input here. However, it's not limited or possible only to use these, there are most effective advanced ways people are establishing connections to their pods.

A.) I am looking at how are you routing your traffic to your `pods` from a load balancer, in general each pod inside Kubernetes cluster by defaults get's its own ip. If we know this how you managing traffic flow from external world to each pod. I can add my answer to `A` part of possible solutions. But not advisable to go this method, because it is more likely your pod dies and a new pod with new ip might get created you need to manually route traffic to the newly created pod, which is why people opted for kubernetes rather than manually managing docker containers on a VM. But I might be wrong, you might be having different complex system it is debatable though.

B.) Like you said, and researched Ingress and Services is also a solution, unfortunately there are no ingress controller annotations available as of now that only limits one connection per pod, but like you said URL based would be one part of the solution but again as you already identified there will be a overhead with this way it is more like single service per single pod and a sub domain for each service. It is more like single deployment with a unique service associated with it and a unique service with unique subdomain. It's a complex setting but doable.

**Edit Based on Comments (Removed HPA)**

Based on the information you added I can suggest a different approach, but it is kinda `wrong` way of using kubernetes, but again it is debatable based on the kind of system you are planning to achieve. Run a proxy server (HAProxy, NGINX, or your fav) on it is own on one of the node and route traffic from the outside world to your pod directly with the internal ip of the pod in your proxy. And you can route based on number of connections, etc from the proxy config remember this is not your kubernetes pod, it's a standalone service your OS running. But caution when node dies pod dies, so is the ip address of the pod.

But this is something we shouldn't do, I am sure in couple of weeks or so you will get the bigger picture of K8s and it's moving parts, you might say this is wrong as there is lot of manual setup overhead.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed and thoughtful response. Yes, I initially went with A.  I set up my instance with an ip per pod. The problem is, they are all behind the load balancer so I have no say in which pod the user gets sent to. Currently we have our prototype running on Azure Container Instances so our server can send a user to each instance, it's just a lot harder because we don't get the autoscale that kubernetes provides.

B could work I suppose. It seems messy to do it URL based but it might be the only reasonable way.

Comment: As far as the horizontal pod autoscaler, I am using that and I think that will not be too hard to configure. My challenge isn't so much scaling as it is getting the load balancer to limit to 1 user per pod.

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like the URL ingress controller route is used for separating services by URL, not individual pods. :(

Comment: If I could only expose pods over the internet for direct connection, I can have the pods update their status and availability using Redis. But exposing each pod for direct connect is what I cannot figure out.

Comment: Hey I updated my answer based on your comments, it's something long so kinda cannot add my answer as comment. And I removed HPA based suggestion as you already achieved something like that.

Comment: I really appreciate it. If only there were a way to do this (using your new approach), but because the IP changes I don't know if it would work. I'm wondering if what I'm trying to do is just not possible or is too unconventional to work within a reasonable amount of effort. Perhaps Azure Container Instances is where I should stay. :(

Comment: Not sure, I am more of a cloud agnostic guy I cannot speak for Azure. The use case you trying to do exists in real world think about Stadia Gaming platform it works similarly each user gets a single pod and each pod has only one connection. I cannot say or confirm it works like that, but if we think it is how possible. So, I think it's doable but need to workout. However, if you achieve it try to add it here it's a fun project.

Comment: If I do end up getting it to work I will post the solution here so others can benefit. It is true that other platforms could offer a solution that works with Kubernetes. Thanks again for the info.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly new to the k8s world, but as I understand it you should be able to do this with the `nginx.org/max-conns` annotation in a Nginx Ingress Controller:

https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/ingress-resources/advanced-configuration-with-annotations/

That way you should be able to limit the number of connections to 1 per 'upstream' or pod.

I.e. the Load Balancer directs traffic to Nginx, Nginx proxies the traffic to pods with one concurrent request per pod.